# Python Bounding a 3D Projection Cut Off by the Z-Axis

Tags: python, numpy, projection

So... I'm trying to project a 3D surface onto the screen.

I've already written code to handle rotations and perspective and everything, and my projection code works exactly as intended when I use it on a numpy array of points.

What I am wondering about is how to apply this to projecting 3D surfaces. Specifically, how exactly should I handle if part of a surface is behind the viewpoint, and part of it is in front of the viewpoint? Would I need to calculate a new surface that represents only the visible portion of the surface I am trying to project?

For example, say I am trying to depict a square with vertices at ([10, 0, 10], [-10, 0, 10], [10, 0, -10], [-10, 0, -10]). Would I need to calculate a new surface with vertices at ([10, 0, 10], [-10, 0, 10], [10, 0, 0], [-10, 0, 0]), and then display that on the screen, or is there a different way to handle planes being cut off by the viewpoint?

With a square, that calculation is trivial, but with an arbitrary surface, the calculation sounds rather inefficient. I feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Along the X and Y axes, there is no problem with drawing things off-screen, but along the Z axis, I am struggling to think of an efficient algorithm that doesn't simply neglect to draw a surface that is partially behind the viewpoint.

Comment: If the surface is triangulated then clipping each triangle results in only 0, 1 or 2 triangles, and you would only do the clipping operation once you know that it intersects one of the frustum planes (which only requires dot products).

Comment: @samgake what if all my surfaces happen to be rectangles (not necessarily aligned with the axes though)? Would it be computationally more efficient to break each down into two triangles?

Comment: If you wrote a special case for rectangles it could be faster, at a cost of more code complexity (the clipping can result in nothing, a triangle, a quad or an irregular pentagon). Triangles are simpler to handle and more robust because the vertices are guaranteed to be coplanar.

Comment: Hmmm okay. The vertices of the rectangles are actually all coplanar, but I am starting to suspect it might still be easier to use triangles.